# Laravel Scopes on DB Builder

Tags: php, laravel, query-builder

I'm totally aware of query scopes on Eloquent and it's working fine. My problem is a bit different, this time I have one query on the DB Query Builder that contains some conditions that are repeated on other models, so I want to extract and reuse these conditions. This is my original query:

```
$grants = $this->grants()
        ->where(function ($query) use ($date) {
            $query->whereDate('grant_date', '<=', $date)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($date) {
                $query->whereNull('canceled')
                    ->whereNull('cost');
            })
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($date) {
                $query->whereDate('canceled', '>', $date);
            });
        })
        ->get();
```

So my idea is to create a scope, let's call `ActiveGrants` just for the sake of the example:

```
public function scopeActiveGrants($query, $date)
{
    return $query->where(function ($query) use ($date) {
        $query->whereDate('grant_date', '<=', $date)
            ->where(function ($query) use ($date) {
                $query->whereNull('canceled')
                    ->whereNull('cost');
            })
            ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($date) {
                $query->whereDate('canceled', '>', $date);
            });
        });
}
```

In order to reuse the scope like this:

```
$grants = $this->grants()
        ->grantsActive()
        ->get();
```

Just a note, `$this->grants()` is a relationship:

```
public function grants()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Grant::class)
}
```

I know Scopes work fine with Eloquent but I couldn't make work with the DB Builder. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I was over-engineering this code refactoring trying to things on the "Laravel" way. Nothing wrong with that, I love the framework and I like to follow its suggestion if makes sense to me. And scopes are pretty cool in my opinion.

I solved this using a regular function to return the Closure that holds all the conditions that I need:

```
   public function activeGrants($date): Closure
   {
       return function ($query) use ($date) {
           $query->whereDate('grant_date', '<=', $date)
               ->where(function ($query) use ($date) {
                   $query->whereNull('cancel')
                        ->whereNull('cost');
                })
                ->orWhere(function ($query) use ($date) {
                    $query->whereDate('cancel', '>', $date);
                });
       };
   }
```

And then:

```
$this->grants()
        ->where($this->grantsUpTo($date))
        ->get();
```

I'm satisfied with this solution, if someone has a better idea please share o/

Comment: In the second block, is it supposed to say `where($this->activeGrants($date))`? Or in the first block, is `activeGrants` supposed to be named `grantsUpTo`?